# Get PP_E_RPS_REASON_OFFERACTIONS_INVALID error key

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I use `GraphServiceClient`

When I try to call:

```
var currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

It works.

BUT when I try to call:

```
var inbox = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

I receive:

> ServiceException: Code: InvalidMsaTicket Message: ErrorCode:
> 'PP_E_RPS_REASON_OFFERACTIONS_INVALID'. Message: ''

why so? What is wrong?

**ADDED:**

When I registered new application, I selected **"Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"** from Supported account types

In result I have:

[image]

client secrets:

[image]

the following authentication:

[image]

[image]

[image]

and API permissions:

[image]

my application has the following auth:

[image]

and the same permissions:

[image]

My `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "https://spoutlookdev.azurewebsites.net",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientId": "2505a5*************5eb",
    "ClientSecret": "Upw8Q~************-UKCa2s",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ],
    "ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    //"Scopes": "mail.read mail.readbasic mail.readbasic.all mail.readwrite user.read"
    "Scopes": "user.read Mail.Read Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite email profile"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

and `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler()
    ;

var config = builder.Configuration;

string[]? initialScopes = config.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(config.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(config.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

NOTE: when it asks permissions, it asks only for base (profile and email), but not asking to read mails. Is it ok?

[image]

What means "Status" in permissions? Some of them marked "Granted for 3MD", some of them - no. Could it affect?

Comment: Does it happen for all users or for specific one?

Comment: one of them receives this error, second - access denied. Also, I modified my post, please review

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try by using Microsoft Graph Explorer and check URl -https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages , if stills it won't work ,let us know what error you were getting .Also try check with the other user , if its user specific or not?

Comment: it works for "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages"

Comment: I modified my post, please review

Comment: Thanks for proving the screenshot of scopes , could you please try by providing User.ReadALL Application permission.

Comment: it did not help

Comment: As we can see on the screenshot that status for User.ReadALL Application permission is not granted . could you please check and try again ,for confirmation you can check the decoding the access token on https://jwt.io